# Why do objects in front and back view look reversed?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

Whenever I model objects that has different look at front and back. Viewing it from front perspective or orthographic the model displays back of the object.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE, Could you share a picture of the problem?

Comment: Often see the terms forward and up for this in importers / exporters. Blender uses -Y forward Z up.  Add a default suzanne (zero loc rot unit scale) and the monkey will be facing in front view because the forward direction of the mesh is the negative local Y axis. (put in local axis mode to visualize)  Your character above is Y forward, that's why you see the back in front view and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Front in Blender is considered to be Y axis, when the camera is facing towards positive Y you see the side of an object facing negative Y direction. This doesn't have to make any sense, it is not supposed to as there is no one logical reason to have it any one particular way.

You can use the shortcuts <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> to quickly switch the viewport to front, side, or top views, you can also hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to reverse the direction when using these hotkeys, <kbd>Numpad 2</kbd>,<kbd>Numpad 4</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad 8</kbd> rotate the view, holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with these 4 will pan it and <kbd>Numpad 9</kbd> reverses to the other side.

You can also use the gizmo at the top right corner for this:

[image]

[See the documentation for more info](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/index.html)

That should really cover all your precise navigation needs whatever side you need to view.

## And I just realized, you might be talking about inverted normals...

Would it hurt to post a picture to help me avoid wasting my time when trying to help?.. Anyway, if you are seeing something like this:

[image]

Go to edit mode(<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select all(<kbd>a</kbd>), open normals menu(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>) and choose flip normals(<kbd>f</kbd>):
[image]