# Objects in front and back view look reversed?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

Am reposting this because I wasn't clear in my previous post.

Check the image to understand my headache.[image]

Comment: Please re-read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164318/why-do-objects-in-front-and-back-view-look-reversed#comment277945_164318  You have aligned your car pointing Y forward.  Y is the green arrow of the axes. Blender uses -Y forward.  On your car the -Y axis is going from bonnet to boot, hence you see the boot (trunk, back of car) in front view.  Another way to look at this is make the side view right ortho instead of left ortho.

Comment: This is exactly the same as  [Why do objects in front and back view look reversed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164318/why-do-objects-in-front-and-back-view-look-reversed)  Please don't ask the same question again if you don't understand the answer, (or comments)

Comment: Am sorry for reposting it. I think I now understand the reason. What I want to know is how to reverse it. Can Rotation on Z axis solve it.