# The y-axis behaves strangely

Tags: keymap

For some reason the Y-axis is behaving strangely. If I press <kbd>NumPad 1</kbd> it gives me the -Y view [image] and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>NumPad 1</kbd> gives me the +Y view [image].

If I activate the mirror on X it gives me a mirror on Y:

[image]

I reset Blender, uninstalled it and reinstalled it. Same thing. I think it's a problem with Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

### It's arbitrary

[Why do objects in front and back view look reversed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/164318/60486)

It's an arbitrary decision (other than complying to the industry standard) for -Y to be front view, and +Y to be back view. It may be surprising and perceived as inconsistent to those who intuitively think front view is *preferred* to back (usually we look at things from the front), and so just like with top/bottom, the *"preferred"* option should have a plus sign (I guess the logic would be you then don't have to use the implied sign every time you describe the more common perspective)

---

As for the mirroring - You choose the coordinate component to be flipped. On the screenshot the shape has all it's vertices copied with same coordinates except X is flipped. Keep in mind there's no Y plane, you would have to specify if you mean YX or YZ plane.

So if your setup was indeed mirroring on the **Y** axis, then the mirrored object should have a narrow part on the bottom, unlike what is seen with the mirror modifier set to **X**:

[image]

Comment: this answer as i remember was the second one

Comment: @hamed.design just below the question you can choose how to sort the answers: https://i.imgur.com/sliEg7K.png

Comment: As far as I know, there is no 'industry standard', not even defacto for this.  Variations are common enough that some CAD software, such as solidworks, actually make it an option to choose whether front is positive or negative Y axis view

Answer (score -2):

[image]

It's true , the mirror on X axis is actually X plane , if you want to understand this when you're pressing  <kbd>G</kbd> and moving an object try to use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd> , it will only move your objects  toward Z plane not Z axis , also you can try <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>X</kbd> to move your object in X plane.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm quite new to Blender but if I understand correctly if I press numpad 1 I should end up on the Y view not -Y.

Comment: @Yaumes That's true already  , almost all of 3d modeling softwares are doing this and it's pretty standard .

Comment: Thanks for your answers. You seem to be right :o)

Comment: There is no X, Y or Z planes. Shift + Z locks Z component of the coordinates, you can move toward Z axis or away from it in that mode, but I fail to see how it's helpful here. 

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady seriously ? you even mentioned that in your answer as YX plane !!! , ok Z plane is the one visible when you're viewing the scene from perspective view all the time (Grid) , z plane is a plane that the normal direction is on z axis , and this is a very design standard rule across all modeling softwares , and if with blender they didn't meant to Z plane , then why we won't press XY , instead of Shift + Z ? I just updated my answer just see the screenshot and upgrade your knowledge .

Comment: I googled and indeed there is Z plane, but it refers to a complex plane or a Z-transform in signal processing...? Not my area of expertise but I think it's unrelated. I figured by now what you mean by X plane is where X = 0. That makes it correct, though you're explaining concept A with concept B, where I'd assume both to be unknown to the OP, and still, the statement about locking "move your objects toward Z plane" is still wrong in your answer.

Comment: @yaumes if you find this answer true and understandable please accept this answer by hitting the correct sign on the left side of this answer .

Comment: [This answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114790/what-is-the-z-plane) from a different stack exchange explains the convention for naming X, Y, and Z planes.  The foo-plane is the plane perpendicular to the foo axis  that contains the two non-foo axis.

Comment: NOTE: In geometry it is more common to use the two non-foo axis to name the plane rather than foo, so the 'Y' plane in gaming is usually the XZ plane in geometry, et cetera.

Comment: @MartyFouts true explanation , if we are naming our self a designer , we must know some design standard principles , its a very simple thing , because we can't make a plane with one axis , when we are naming a plane with one axis we mean a plane with normal toward that axis , its not neede to be that smart to understood . Sorry for bad eng .